# ejabberd mysql script bug?

Tags: mysql, ejabberd

Hihi, not sure if i am just plain dumb.. Have installed ejabberd on amazon ec2 and recently managed to switch to use mysql based on the guide: https://support.process-one.net/doc/display/MESSENGER/Using+ejabberd+with+MySQL+native+driver

I have an issue now after switching to mysql db, not able to add roster to my user, and the log shows that the table rosterusers does not exist.

And now I am confusing, I grabbed the mysql.sql db schema from ejabberd github at https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/src/odbc/mysql.sql, and found that

1. there isn't any rosterusers table to be created, instead, it creates a table called rosteritem.
2. there isn't any table called rostergroups, but rostergroup (without 's'). After some googling around, i think rostergroups should be the correct naming.

Is there anyone here knows is this a bug in the mysql schema, or i am missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not gotten any feedback regarding this question, but eventually, I have manually changed some of the table schema created from the mysql.sql script to matched the one from mssql.sql.

Everything works fine thereafter!

:)

Comment: Hey, Please can you let me know step-by-step, how you have connected the ejabberd with mysql database ?